# siunitx per-mode and math in s-column

Tags: tables, math-mode, siunitx

I am trying to use an `siunitx` `s`-column with `per-mode = reciprocal` for an units column but want to have my unit multiplied with a power. If there is a native way to do this with `siunitx` I missed it, so I used standard math instead. It seems an `s`-column implies math mode, so I just typed the power right after the units as `\cubic\meter\per\mole \times10^{-5}`. This works al right (despite feeling a little hacky) but where as in all other rows of the same table the `per-mode`-setting of `reciprocal` is respected, in the cell with the extra math, the `\per` is typeset as `fraction` with a `/`. When I remove the math, it is correctly typeset as `reciprocal` with a `^-1`.

What is the correct way of doing this with `siunitx` if I don't want to introduce another column as the horizontal space is already quite limited due to two-column paper-style document layout?

Here the complete table:
Relevant loaded packages and options from the preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{
        per-mode = symbol,
        output-decimal-marker = {.},
        list-final-separator = { und },
        list-pair-separator = { und },
        range-phrase = { bis },
        separate-uncertainty = true
    }
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centerline{
        \begin{tabular}{
            l
            s[table-unit-alignment=left, per-mode=reciprocal]
            S[table-format=3.3(2)]
            S[{table-format=3.3, table-space-text-post=~[0]}]
        }
            \toprule
                                    &                                           & {Experiment}      & {Literatur} \\
            \midrule
            \( p_\mathrm{c} \)      & \bar                                      &  37.3  +-  0.5    &  37.59    ~\cite{DeanLange}           \\
            \( V_\mathrm{c,mol} \)  & \cubic\centi\meter\per\mole               & 238    +- 32      & 198.05    ~\cite{BrakerAllen}     \\
            \( T_\mathrm{c} \)      & \degreeCelsius                            &  47    +-  1      &  45.6     ~\cite{Merck}               \\
            \( K_\mathrm{c} \)      &                                           &   3.00 +-  0.32   &   3.56                                \\
            \( a \)                 & \pascal\meter\tothe{6}\per\mole\tothe{2}  &   0.8  +-  0.53   &  78.57    ~\cite{ReidPrausnitzPoling} \\
            \( b \)                 & \cubic\meter\per\mole \times10^{-5}       &  88.5  +-  0.47   &   9.795   ~\cite{ReidPrausnitzPoling} \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The problematic column is the second one, the problematic cell is in the last row. Specifically `\cubic\meter\per\mole \times10^{-5}`

(And yes, the experimental values are just non-sense, we didn't measure yet. FYI the measurement is about the Van-der-Waals gas behaviour of sulfur hexafluoride.)

Comment: It is a lot easier to help if you provide an MWE, that can be copied and tested as is without havving to add anything. BTW: It is pure luck that this works: `p_\mathrm{c}`, consider making a habit of using `p_{\mathrm{c}}` just to be on the save side.

Comment: I transformed the code blocks into a mwe and clearified the location of the problem. It's not the `p_c`, rather the `\times10^{-5}`. Enclosing the `\times10^{-5}` in brackets like `\cubic\meter\per\mole {\times10^{-5}}` didn't change anything. Or is there another reason why you suggest to bracket the subscript (apart from clearity?)

Comment: IT was for clarity and such that others coming by this question do not think this is something they should do in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First to your main issue which is the `\times 10^{-5}`. I think you are confusing the `s` column here, because you enter stuff that cannot be handled by `siunitx`. So I think `siunitx` escapes the `s` mode and so this cell is handled similar as if you would have bracketed it `{...}`. (As a hint you can just enter in a dummy row `\cubic\meter\per\mole` which will be handled correctly, but when you then just add let's say `a` after it, you will see that the output is switched back to the `per` mode, which is valid "outside" the `s` column. Maybe this is a bug that the column is still interpreting the unit stuff correctly (so without marking it with `\si`). We will see when Joseph has a look at the question ;))

So in my opinion the correct way would be to escape the `s` column by bracketing the cell and put in it your desired content, i.e. `{\SI{e5}{\cubic\metre\per\mole}}`.

Then I did some more changes to your table:

1. I introduced a new column type `L` so you don't need to repeat the math mode for each cell. From that follows that you have to handle a possible heading different. Here I simply have chosen to use the `\text` command, but could also have used `\multicolumn`.
2. Because the given headings are in German, as well as the given keys to `siunitx` which used translated values I assume you want to produce a German result. That could be done a bit easier by just setting `locale=DE`. But it can be done even cleverer by choosing the appropriate settings depending on the active language. For that I have added the languages `english` and `ngerman` to the `\documentclass` and added the `babel` package. Then you can add the `locale`s to the language using the `\addto` command (have a look at the code below). (You can test it by uncommenting the `\selectlanguage` line.)
3. Last I have moved the `\cite`s to a separate column and used another `\multicolumn` command to center the heading above both column. To achieve that only the desired space is set between the two columns I use the `@{...}` expression, which "[kills the inter-column space and replaces it with whatever is between the curly braces](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#.40-expressions)". In this case the space I use `@{~}`, but could have used any other space generating command.
4. I have corrected the number of decimal digits to `2` in the first `S` column. At least for the given MWE this is the maximum number given.

Last I wanted to note that you could make use of the `cellspace` package (already present in the following code) to "enlarge" the spacing of cells with "large" content, e.g. a math symbol having both, a subscript and a superscript. To use it simply replace the line `\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}` by `\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}Cl<{$}}`. (For more details have a look at the [`cellspace` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cellspace/cellspace.pdf).)

---

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    10pt,
    twocolumn,
    english,ngerman,
        ]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\usepackage{cellspace}
    \addtolength\cellspacetoplimit{2pt}
    \addtolength\cellspacebottomlimit{2pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{
        per-mode = symbol,
        separate-uncertainty = true,
    }
    % add appropriate `locale' values to the corresponding languages
    \addto\extrasenglish{\sisetup{locale = UK}}
    \addto\extrasngerman{\sisetup{locale = DE}}
\begin{document}
%    \selectlanguage{english}
\begin{table}[htbp]
        \newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
    \centerline{
        \begin{tabular}{
            L
            s[table-unit-alignment=left, per-mode=reciprocal]
            S[table-format=3.2(2)]
            S[table-format=3.3]
            @{~}l
        }
                \toprule
            \text{Symbol}     & {Einheit}                                 & {Experiment}      & \mc{Literatur} \\
                \midrule
            p_\mathrm{c}      & \bar                                      &  37.3  +-  0.5    &  37.59    & \cite{DeanLange}           \\
            V_\mathrm{c,mol}  & \cubic\centi\meter\per\mole               & 238    +- 32      & 198.05    & \cite{BrakerAllen}     \\
            T_\mathrm{c}      & \degreeCelsius                            &  47    +-  1      &  45.6     & \cite{Merck}               \\
            K_\mathrm{c}      &                                           &   3.00 +-  0.32   &   3.56                                \\
            a                 & \pascal\meter\tothe{6}\per\mole\tothe{2}  &   0.8  +-  0.53   &  78.57    & \cite{ReidPrausnitzPoling} \\
            b                 & {\SI{e5}{\cubic\meter\per\mole}}          &  88.5  +-  0.47   &   9.795   & \cite{ReidPrausnitzPoling} \\
                \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough answer :) I did in fact use the `babel` package, just didn't include it in the mwe. But I didn't know about `\extrasngerman{}` thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Ps0ke, you are welcome. And just in case you should also use `tikz`/`pgf`/`pgfplots` ... Then you could further extend it to `\addto\extrasenglish{\sisetup{locale = DE}\SendSettingsToPgf}` which would also set the `number format` appropriately.    I also just realized that I have missed to explain how the `cellspace` package could be used. Do you know it or shall I extend my answer explaining it?

Comment: I would be grateful if you could elaborate on the `cellspace` package. Also, for the sake of completeness, what is the reasoning behind the `@{~}` in the last column type?

Comment: @Ps0ke, I just edited my answer. Is that sufficient for you?

Comment: it's perfect. Thank you very much for your extensive answer and helpfulness. The tex.stackexchange.com community is really awesome!

Comment: @Ps0ke, I fully agree to the last sentence ;)